# Use Livecd to recover ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, live-cd

I accidentally deleted /usr/share. My system is unbootable now.

I have a backup of /usr/share in the form of simple copy and paste. But my linux ubuntu 20.04 system is un writeable upon booting with live usb.

Kindly guide me on restoring files by copy-paste When i boot from ubuntu livecd.

Comment: Just a quick note, in case you didn't realize... when you boot into a Live CD and you navigate to a path (such as `/usr/share`, for example), you are viewing the files on the Live CD, and there are naturally unwritable. When you say your system is "un writeable upon booting with live usb" are you referring to these files on the Live CD, or have you already mounted your *installed* Linux file system somewhere?

Comment: What leads you to believe that the /usr/share on the LiveUSB is identical to what you erased? You have *destroyed* your system. Backup your data and reinstall.

Comment: You haven't indicated what release you have installed? and if the *live* CD matches that exactly?  (eg. are you using a *daily* image that matches your systems release and your upgrade level? as even if you're doing that, you'll likely have added packages to your installed system, that won't be on the *live* system).  Grabbing the files from your backup, or installing to a VM/different-box & grabbing from there (once you've made it equivalent) maybe safer...

Answer (score 0):

Things you could try:

- trying to unmount the partition and mounting again rw.
- copying the files using `sudo cp`
- transferring the files using `rsync`
- re-installing the whole system, instead of copying

The last one is what I would normally do, since it works 100% of the time and it's fast. I assume you have a backup of your data as well and can reinstall all previously installed programs with a simple script.